# Exclude the radial lines in a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have a graph formed by the edges 
`{4 <-> 1, 1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 5}`. Then I define my own line numbers to those edges as `{5,6,7,8,9}`.

1. How to identify and exclude the radial edge (In this case it is `1 <-> 5`) and give only the edges which are in the mesh part.
   I could use `FindFundamentalCycles` to exclude the radial edge. But, it only gives edges, not line numbers. Now how can I get the line numbers? In this case I want to get `{5,6,7,8}`.

Comment: Please define "radial edge" precisely.

Comment: @Szabolcs. I am not perfectly clear about graph theory. But in my sense, a radial line is the edge which do not form a loop

Answer (score 2):

```
edges = {4 <-> 1, 1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 5};
indices = Range[5, 9];

Pick[indices, Unitize @ Total @EdgeCycleMatrix @ edges, 1]
```

> {5, 6, 7, 8}

```
Pick[indices, Total @ EdgeCycleMatrix @ edges, 0]
```

> {9}

Alternatively,

```
Pick[indices, Boole @ MemberQ[Flatten @ FindFundamentalCycles @ edges, #] & /@ edges, 1]
```

> {5, 6, 7, 8}

```
Pick[indices, Boole @ MemberQ[Flatten @ FindFundamentalCycles @ edges, #] & /@ edges, 0] 

MapIndexed[If[MemberQ[Flatten@FindFundamentalCycles@edges, #] , Nothing, 
   indices[[First@#2]]] &, edges]
```

> {9}